# Пунктуация при слове "итого": какой знак предпочтительнее?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, оформление-текста, тире-или-двоеточие, пробелы

В документальной литературе, например, в тех же таблицах или подписях под ними, привычно видеть, что после "итого" либо ничего не стоит, либо стоит двоеточие ("итого десять", "итого: десять"). А как быть, если "итого" употребляется в тексте сугубо художественном? В "Нацкорпусе" нашлись примеры, где после "итого" может стоять и запятая, и тире, и двоеточие, и ничего (см. [Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&mode=main&nodia=1&p=0&req=%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%E2%80%94%20&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexform))... Как вы считаете, в каком случае что предпочтительнее? Вероятно, в расчёт стоит брать возможность замены (итого = в итоге / итого = как результат / итого = на выходе...). Можно подумать на примере.

*Слева — пятеро стрелков. Справа — трое, один из них с пулемётом. По прямой — двое, оба — автоматчики. Итого(?) десять. Расклад, прямо скажем, хреновый.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Слева — пятеро стрелков. Справа — трое, один из них с пулемётом. По прямой — двое, оба — автоматчики. **ИтогО — десять.** Расклад, прямо скажем, хреновый.*

Большинство ответов можно найти в толковом словаре:

**ИТОГО**, нареч. В общей сумме, всего (употр. в конце перечисления каких-л. сумм). И. необходимо триста рублей. На другой язык переведено итого двадцать страниц текста.

Здесь знаков нет. Двоеточие или тире будут **интонационными** (авторскими) знаками.

**Тире** ставится при наличии пузы (при повышении тона), а **двоеточие** — при интонационном предупреждении (понижение тона перед подчеркнутой паузой). Здесь, как мне кажется, лучше подходит тире.